# get first element from dictionary which is an array - python

Tags: python, http-headers

I have an array store header information:

```
{'x-frame-options': {'defined': True, 'warn': 0, 'contents': 'SAMEORIGIN'}, 'strict-transport-security': {'defined': True, 'warn': 0, 'contents': 'max-age=15552000'}, 'access-control-allow-origin': {'defined': False, 'warn': 1, 'contents': ''}, 'content-security-policy': {'defined': True, 'warn': 0, 'contents': "upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com"}, 'x-xss-protection': {'defined': False, 'warn': 1, 'contents': ''}, 'x-content-type-options': {'defined': False, 'warn': 1, 'contents': ''}}
```

I want to get the first element of the dictionary

```
#header is a return array that store all header information,

headers = headersecurity.verify_header_existance(url, 0)
for header in headers:
    if header.find("x-frame-options"):
        for headerSett in header:
            defined = [elem[0] for elem in headerSett.values()] # here I don't get first element
            print(defined)
```

the expected results is:

```
x-frame-options : defined = True;
access-control-allow-origin : defined = True;
x-content-type-options : defined = True;
....
```

thanks

Comment: There is no array at all in the headers, so there is no way of **first** element. Please explain what value you expect

Comment: `dict`s are unordered. There's no "first". Why can't you index it using its keys?

Comment: i want to get the value : defined

Comment: ...so use `"defined"` as your key. `elem["defined"]`, not `elem[0]`.

Comment: but I want it in a way I get defined for all other headers

Comment: I don't understand what that means. The change I suggested just indexes `elem` by key instead of by position.

Comment: replacing by elem["defined"]  doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Then you probably haven't identified the correct problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'd be safer to use dictionary keys like so

```
headers['x-frame-options']['defined']
```

That way you do not rely on the ordering inside the dict (dict are not ordered)

EDIT: Just saw your edit and what you are expecting as an output, here a simple way of having it:

```
for key, value in headers.items():
    if "defined" in value:
        print(f"{key} : defined = {value['defined']}")
```

output:

```
x-frame-options : defined = True
strict-transport-security : defined = True
access-control-allow-origin : defined = False
content-security-policy : defined = True
x-xss-protection : defined = False
x-content-type-options : defined = False
```

Comment: one quick question, how i can print just the value ''defined'' of each header?

Comment: Just replace what's in the print statement